# Expression.MethodCallExpression pass MemberExpression as Parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

I'm trying to create a generic Expression with a method call on

> Enumerable.Contains

So basically i want to achive this simple lambda

> x => collection.Contains(x.SomeProperty)

My code so far is looking like this:

```
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyName);

MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable),
    "Contains",
    new Type[] { typeof(Object) },
    Expression.Constant(new Object[] { 1, 2, 3 }),
    memberExpression
);
```

But then it dumps

> InvalidOperationException: No generic method 'Contains' on type    'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type
>   arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the
>   method is non-generic

If i just pass the paramterExpression it works fine, but thats not what i want.

My question is now. Is there a way to pass the Memberexpression to the Contains mehtod call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the `Type` of `memberExpression` which in turn depends on the type that the property accessed has.

E.g. the following works:

```
void Main()
{
    string propertyName = "ObjectProperty";
    ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyName);
    MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        "Contains",
        new Type[] { typeof(object) },
        Expression.Constant(new Object[] { 1, 2, 3 }),
        memberExpression
    );

    Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodCall, parameterExpression).Compile()(new T()));
}

public class T
{
    public object ObjectProperty => 2;
    public int IntProperty => 4;
}
```

The following does not:

```
void Main()
{
    string propertyName = "IntProperty";
    ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyName);
    MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        "Contains",
        new Type[] { typeof(object) },
        Expression.Constant(new Object[] { 1, 2, 3 }),
        memberExpression
    );

    Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodCall, parameterExpression).Compile()(new T()));
}

public class T
{
    public object ObjectProperty => 2;
    public int IntProperty => 4;
}
```

You could use `new Type[] { memberExpression.Type }` instead of `new Type[] { typeof(object) }` to have the code adapt to the type of the property, though you'd also need to have the type of the argument expression (in this case the `Constant(new Object[] {...}`)) match.

Note that you can do implicit casts here only if they are reference types that derive from the type in question (`object`) so a property that returned `string` or `Uri` would be fine (though obviously always false in the check for whether it was contained in an array of `1, 2, 3`) but a property that returned `int` is not as it's a boxing conversion, not a reference up-cast.